# How to make use of the XPath Function, string-length( [string] ) in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I came to know that `string-length` returns the number of characters in the string. for e.g.,

> //input[string-length( [string] )]

If so how to get the characters using Selenium? It would be great, If I get any examples or working code on that from google.com

Answer (score 0):

Your query returns the n-th `<input/>` element of each context, where n is the length of `[string]`.

If you want to return the string-length of a single element, use `string-lenght(//input)`. Be aware that you with XPath 1.0 (which is the only one supported by selenium), you cannot return the string length of multiple objects.